# ssis load failed externalrequest_post "IDBinitialize::Initialize Failed" the external request has completed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I deployed a working SSIS project to a new faster computer hoping for better performance and instead I got the following error

> Failed90:external_request_post "IDBinitialize::Initialize Failed" the
> external request has completed

Any ideas?  I migrated it from a slower computer that had the same steup, that is, Windows 10 Pro.  Sql 15.0.2000.5.  It worked on the previous computer.

Comment: Connection sting needs updating.  Use SQL Server Management Studio and check login window for server\instance and update your connection string.  Also do a query from SSMS to make sure there are not issues with credentials.

Answer (score 0):

@jdweng was close.  It turns out the connection string was correct, but I hadn't configured the local sql instance to permit SQL Server authentication mode.  I found the failed logins in my SQL Management logs.  After enabling, it worked.